# How can send emails with comma separated

Tags: php, laravel

I have multiple emails in one column..

How can send email these email with comma separated?

smith1@gmail.com smith2@gmail.com

```
    $emails = explode(',', $project->emails);

    if (!empty($project->emails)) {
      Mail::to($emails)->send(new ProjectMail( $project ));  
    }
```

coming this error

```
Swift_RfcComplianceException: Address in mailbox given [smith1@gmail.com smith2@gmail.com] does not comply with RFC 2822, 3.6.2.
```

Comment: Do you want to send an email to every address separately, or do you want to send one email to all the addresses in one go?

Comment: Exploding by comma won't do much since there is no comma in that string, explode by space

Comment: @zlatan bro i want to send one email to all the addresses which are saved in one go

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to transform this string in an array, that is separated by the comma, using [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
$mails = 'smith1@gmail.com smith2@gmail.com';
$explodedMails = explode(' ', $mails);
```

This will give you following structure:

```
=> [
     "smith1@gmail.com",
     "smith2@gmail.com",
   ]
```

Then, you send the email to all the given addresses in `$explodedMails` array:

```
Mail::to($explodedMails)->send(new ProjectMail( $project ));
```

This will send one email to all the addresses from the $explodedEmail array:

[image: example]

Comment: Thans bro for helping me. I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use str_replace and replace space between mail with comma

```
str_replace("",',',$yourEmailVar);
```

or you can explode your mails and use cc method for sending mails to all!

Answer (score 0):

Use an explode function and instead of replacing with a **comma**,replace with the **blank space** since apparently in the variable mentioned by you,there does not seem to be any **commas**. Write the code as follows :

```
$mail_ids = 'smith1@gmail.com smith2@gmail.com';
$mailArray = explode(' ', $mail_ids);
```

The above explode function will give you an array in proper format like ['smith1@gmail.com','smith2@gmail.com'] and then you can use that array for your purpose of sending email ids.